# Django/django-taggit -- How to access filtered tag name in template

Tags: django, django-taggit

I'm looking for the right syntax to access my tag name.

Here's my view:

```
def tag_filter(request, tag):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    concerts = Concert.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[tag])\
                              .filter(date__gte=now).order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'concerts/calendar.html', {'concerts': concerts})
```

This is indeed getting the data I want. I'd like to display the name of the tag in the header of my template, but this is where I'm running into a snag. I'm trying this:

```
  {% elif request.resolver_match.url_name == "tag_filter" %}
  <h1>Upcoming Events with "{{ concerts.0.tags.name }}" Tag</h1>
  {% endif %}
```

But `{{ concerts.0.tags.name }}` is returning nothing. I've tried a few variations but nothing so far. Any ideas? Thank you!

Editing to add my `urlconf`, just in case that's relevant:

```
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[\w-]+)/$', views.tag_filter, name="tag_filter"),
```

Comment: can you `print(concerts)` just right before you render your view, and show us the output? maybe the queryset was empty

Comment: If I go in the shell and run the query above, then run `print concerts[0].tags.all()`, I get `<QuerySet [<Tag: rock>, <Tag: electronica>]>`. But I really just want to get the same tag as is in my url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just added the 'tag': tag, to my context dictionary, then I can easily call {{ tag }} in the template. Hope this helps someone in the future. :)

View:

```
def tag_filter(request, tag):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    concerts = Concert.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[tag])\
                              .filter(date__gte=now).order_by('date')
    return render(request, 'concerts/calendar.html', {'concerts': concerts,
                                                      'tag': tag})
```

Template:

```
  {% elif request.resolver_match.url_name == "tag_filter" %}
  <h1>Upcoming Events with "{{ tag }}" Tag</h1>
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Concert has a `ManyToManyField` to `tags`, so when you do: `{{ concerts.0 }}`, you have access to a `Concert` instance. `{{ concerts.0.tags }}` and there you have access to many tags as Concert has Many Tags.

So if you want to display one tag, you need to slice one

```
{{ concerts.0.tags.0.name }}
```

Or if you want to display all the tags related to that Concert, you can use {% for loop %}

```
<h1>Upcoming Events with "{% for tag in concerts.0.tags.all %}{{ tag }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}{% endfor %}" Tag</h1>
```

`{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}` is only to add a comma `,` as a separator between tags.